# What models exist to analyse scattered points in a box?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, model-selection, model

I have a box with points scattered around in it. Just imagine any surrounding border with points inside of it. Something like this:

[image]

I want to use statistics to analyze the scatter of these points, so that I can say something about where they are most likely to fall. Possibly I will also have some independent variables that may influence the results.

**So what possible models exist to analyze this (doesn't matter if they are complicated, I can read up on it)?**

My first idea was that since the data is given as two coordinates, I essentially can do either univariate regression on each coordinate, or multivariate regression. This allows me to include my independent variables.

However, I am unsure how I would use this strategy to "visualize" what areas are more likely. What I would like is something like this:

[image]

Here, the red curve is supposed to represent some sort of 90 % "confidence interval" so to speak. Could I do this with the method above? And if not, what other model could I use to get results like this, and would they allow to adjust for independent variables?

Comment: Are you interested only in position, or does the size of the dots/points also count?